# Scout SDK Android: Calculate distance between 2 SkCoordinate in km

Tags: android, skmaps

Working with Scout SDK 2.4.0.
I would like to present results from offline search with information about distance from current location to result address locations.

I see that this kind of calculation is performed by `SKRouteManager.getInstance().calculateRoute(route);`.

The question - is there any simplest way delivered from Scout SDK for this type of calculation? Seems that I cannot use SKRouteManager for calculation in loop, because it is singleton.

EDIT:

```
for (SearchResultStackEntry searchResultStackEntry : resultStack) {
            SKCoordinate skCoordinate = searchResultStackEntry.getRefinedLocation();
            SKRouteSettings route = new SKRouteSettings();
            route.setNoOfRoutes(1);
            route.setRouteMode(SKRouteSettings.SKRouteMode.CAR_FASTEST);
            route.setDestinationCoordinate(new SKCoordinate(skCoordinate.getLongitude(), skCoordinate.getLatitude()));
            route.setStartCoordinate(new SKCoordinate(LocationManager.getInstance().getCurrentPosition().getCoordinate().getLongitude(), LocationManager.getInstance().getCurrentPosition().getCoordinate().getLatitude()));
            SKRouteManager.getInstance().calculateRoute(route);
}
```

If I used it like this `SKRouteManager.getInstance().getNumberOfRoutes()` returns always 0. I am sure about the passed coordinates values.

After some tests I realise, that we should wait for listener callback. Before this callback skRouteInfo object is not valid.

Finding route for 100 rows cost me 16 seconds.
Looking for better implementation....

Comment: Currently calling calculateRoute in a loop would be the only possible way of getting this information - why do you say it is not possible? Can you attach a code snippet of the code you're using?

Comment: Question updated with code snipped.

Comment: add route.setRouteExposed(false) and make sure that the map data on which you want to route is available onboard (i.e. have the city/country package downloaded and installed) - what's the time for this setup?